# C# : how do I get an XmlSchemaElement from and XmlSchema

Tags: c#

From this XML schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema 
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="d">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Campaign">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
              <xs:element name="CampaignId" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="ImplementationId" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="SentDate" type="xs:date" />
            </xs:all>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="CampaignTargetGroupMembers" maxOccurs="unbounded" >
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="OutboundId" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="TargetGroupMemberAttributeData">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:all>
                    <xs:element name="AttributeId" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="Value" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="EdmTypeId" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="OutboundId" type="xs:string" />
                  </xs:all>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="InteractionType" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I want to get the `XmlSchemaElement` for `CampaignTargetGroupMembers`. But I can't seem to figure it out.

I've tried this:

```
XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemaSet.Add("", @"Feedback.xsd");

XmlSchema schema = schemaSet.Schemas().OfType<XmlSchema>().First();

foreach (XmlSchemaElement value in schema.Elements.Values) {
    Console.WriteLine($"XmlSchemaElement name = {value.Name}");
}
```

I'm only getting one `XmlSchemaElement` from `schema.Elements.Values` which is the root `d` element but there doesn't seem to be any way to get the child elements from it.

How do I get the `XmlSchemaElement` that I need?

edit:

I'm writing out large xml files using `XmlWriter`. I'd like to validate the output as I go, before writing it. The files will have 10s of thousands to over a million records.

I'm trying to use `XElement.Validate(XmlSchemaObject, XmlSchemaSet, ValidationEventHandler)`. If I understand this correctly the `XmlSchemaObject` needs to be the `XmlSchemaElement` from the schema for the element that I'm trying to validate.

Comment: I'm afraid that's impossible. If you extract an element named `CampaignTargetGroupMembers`, it will contain the `maxOccurs` attribute, which is not allowed at the single schema element. Therefore, validation is not possible by it.

Comment: Thanks Alexander Petrov. Your comment suggests that there is a way to extract an XmlSchemaElement for CampaignTargetGroupMembers. If so, how would I do that?

Comment: I created it manually.